# How to get the last 4 Hidden states from the feature extraction pipeline

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, pipeline, huggingface-transformers

I have defined a pipeline for Feature extraction

```
bio_gpt = AutoModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt", output_hidden_states= True)
bio_gpt = bio_gpt.to(device)

# Create the pipeline
p = pipeline(
    task="feature-extraction",
    tokenizer="microsoft/biogpt",
    model="microsoft/biogpt",
    framework="pt",
    device=0
)
```

and I want to extract the embeddings of the last token of the last hidden state, and the Average Pooling of the last 4 layers using the pipeline approach I am doing it like this

*Last token of the last hidden state:*

```
def extract_last_token(last_hidden_states):
    last_hidden_states = np.array(last_hidden_states)
    return last_hidden_states[:,-1,:]

# Process the data using the pipeline
results = p([row["text"] for _, row in df2.iterrows()])

# Extract the last token of the last hidden state
embeddings = [extract_last_token(hidden_state) for hidden_state in results]

# Create a DataFrame to store the results
df2["embeddings2"] = embeddings
```

*Average pooling of the last 4 layers:*

```
def mean_pooling(last_hidden_states, ):
    last_4_layers = last_hidden_states[-4:]  # Consider the last 4 layers
    return np.mean(last_4_layers, axis=1)

# Process the data using the pipeline
results = p([row["text"] for _, row in df2.iterrows()])

features = np.squeeze(results)

print(features.shape)
# Perform mean pooling on the last hidden states
embeddings = [mean_pooling(hidden_state) for hidden_state in results]

# Create a DataFrame to store the results
df2["embeddings4"] = embeddings
```

The issues are:

- When I extract the embeddings of the 4 last layers or the 12 last layers the embeddings are always the same

[image: embeddings 4 layers and 12 layers]

- The embeddings of the last token of the last hidden state are different from the same embeddings using the "manual" method

[image: last token embeddings manual and pipeline]

Weardly in the above picture the 2 of the embeddings are the same but oposite row ids, this indicates another problem I dont see it if you can spot this I apreciate it.

Here is the code how I did the manual version

````
output = bio_gpt(**model_inputs)

# Get the last state
last_state = output.last_hidden_state

cls_embeddings = last_state[:, -1, :]

# Print the last state
print(cls_embeddings)

# Assign cls_embeddings to "embeddings4" column in df2
df2["embeddings_manual"] = [cls_embeddings[i].cpu().detach().numpy() for i in range(len(df2))] ```
````